# Compile time error on missing specialization for a traits class

Tags: c++

Given a traits base class like

```
template<typename T>
class Trait {
public:
    const bool isCapableOfSomething = false;

    static void doSomething() {
        // Raise compile time error here
    }
};
```

I am wondering how to raise an error if someone tries to call `doSomething()` with a type that the trait has not been specialized for.

I came along like 1000 solutions just on Stackoverflow. Among others variations, most solutions use `static_assert`s or SFINAE to various degrees. Yet, while following these solutions and experimenting, I came up with the following little snippet:

```
template<typename T>
class Trait {
public:
    const bool isCapableOfSomething = false;

    static void doSomething() {
        (void) Error::This_trait_is_not_capable_of_doing_something();
    }

private:
    template<typename X>
    struct Error { };
};
```

In contrast to most SFINAE-based solutions, this is quite simple to understand (the `(void)` could even be removed), it does not rely on `static_assert` or the workarounds provided by, e.g. boost (unfortunately, `static_assert` is still not supported everywhere I need it) and it generates an error message as compact as

```
'This_trait_is_not_capable_of_doing_something' is not a member of 'Trait<SomeType>::Error<SomeType>'
         (void) Error<T>::This_trait_is_not_capable_of_doing_something();
```

Now I am just wondering whether this is valid C++ or am I missing some caveat.

Comment: Just FYI, you can make `static_assert()` not raise an error immediately by making it dependent on a template parameter, something like `static_assert(static_cast<T *>(nullptr), "error message")`.  This forces evaluation to be delayed until the member function is instantiated.

Comment: A second templated class that has a constant defined as `false` also works. Let's refer to this as the *always_false* trick for now. Yet, I don't like the complicated mess around it...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your proposed solution, though I'd prefer `static_cast<void>()` instead of a C-style cast. And a side note, I suspect this question would be better asked on the code review stack exchange since it's asking for a review of working code.

Comment: cdhowie, I actually wasn't aware of the code review stack exchange. Good Point!